# Flutter App Signing error - "No such file or directory"

Tags: flutter

I am trying to sign the app on flutter with the code

`/Applications/Android\Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

as soon as i press enter i get the following error

`zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

replace the `c:\Users\USER_NAME` to Your username path

Comment: thanks but the problem is after i run flutter doctor -v to gather the java binary from the Android Toolchain section --> i then replace the last word java with the keytool again and run it --> and thats when i see this error 
`zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`